# Get files using TreeView library

Tags: java, android, file, treeview

### First of all sorry my English is not good I will accept any edits of my question, [this](https://github.com/AmrDeveloper/TreeView) is the library link.

---

I have already test the library and worked well, This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOWDM.jpg).
But I need to get files located in storage path `/storage/emulated/0/` to a treeview recyclerview something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pJVd.jpg).

### Codes

---

Since the codes are large I cant post them here so the codes are same located in this [link](https://github.com/AmrDeveloper/TreeView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/amrdeveloper/treeviewlib/filestree). Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post your code please. No links. And your picture shows a tree of java and c files. Looks from your ide. Of your pc?

Comment: Your issue is on github with a nice answer: https://github.com/AmrDeveloper/TreeView/issues/4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.